# Lazy reading of a file line by line as needed in python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, lazy-loading

I am very new to python. I have many HUGE txt files (csv comma delimited) that I need to read in and process simultaneously. I have a function like the one below that gets called once I want the next line to be read. However, this function assumes that the data is already in a python collection in RAM. This is exactly what I am trying to avoid, as it overwhelms RAM even after reading a few files from thousands still to read.

Is there a way I can turn this into a get_new_bar_one_line_at_a_time_from_file? Thing is, I want to make it pretty transparent to the user of the function. A memory mapped file where the (overloaded) operator [] read in a single line automatically and **yield** it would probably be most transparent?

```
import pandas as pd

self.symbol_data = {}

self.symbol_data[s] = pd.read_csv(fullPath,
                                          decimal='.', 
                                          sep=',', 
                                          #chunksize = 4, #if use chunksize doesn't work with indexing
                                          #parse_dates=[[0,1]], 
                                          index_col=[0]
                                  )

# This doesn't work if I enable chunking above.But if no indexing, then nothing works
#comb_index = self.symbol_data[s].index

def get_new_bar(self, symbol): 
    for b in self.symbol_data[symbol]:
        yield tuple([symbol, b[0], b[1][0], b[1][1], b[1][2], b[1][3], b[1][4], b[1][5], b[1][6]])
```

and I call it like this

```
for s in self.symbol_list:    
    gen = iter(self.get_new_bar(s))
    bar = gen.next()
```

Would love if I could say

```
def lazy_get_new_bar(self, symbol): 
    for b in self.symbol_data_from_file[symbol]:
        yield tuple([symbol, b[0], b[1][0], b[1][1], b[1][2], b[1][3], b[1][4], b[1][5], b[1][6]])
```

where the b[]s knew that it needed to get the next line from the file and only that line, and all the while works with Pandas.

Comment: Look into pytables/hdf5, pandas doesn't have real support for this kind of thing just yet.

Comment: @U2EF1 I beg to differ: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk

Comment: Jeff, I tried your chunking. I had to remove indexing in order to get it to work. Now I get trivial errors when I access data, e.g., yield tuple([symbol, b[0], b[1][0], b[1][1], b[1][2], b[1][3], b[1][4], b[1][5], b[1][6]]) gives a stacktrace at bottom is:  File "hashtable.pyx", line 704, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:11861)

Comment: I am not sure indexing makes sense in the presence of chunking...

Comment: @Ivan not sure what you are trying to do here. chunking gives you a smaller (chunksize frame).